# Issue with VBScript to rename and move log files

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a problem a vbscript I'm working on.
The script renames, then moves some FTP log files from one folder to another.
The script is working, but then I realised I have a file called delete_junkfiles.log, but I do not want this file to be renamed or moved, just left in place in the source folder.

At present the script is renaming and moving all files.
The script also throws a file not found error, even though the files are renamed then moved, if possible I would like to fix this as well....

I know for you vbscript experts, this is probably really easy, but I'm fairly new to vbs and I just can't figure out how to ignore the delete_junkfiles.log and just leave it alone.
Any help you guy's could put my would be greatly appreciated.
Below is my script....

```
Dim WshShell, FileManagement, BrowseDialogBox, SelectedFolder, OldString, NewString, FullPath, TheFolder, FileList
Dim File, ThisFile, TheString, AlreadyRenamed, TempName, FlagName, Success, FindFlag, NewName, Dummy

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FileManagement = WScript.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set BrowseDialogBox = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set SelectedFolder = BrowseDialogBox.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the folder containing the files you want to rename.", &H0001)

If InStr(1, TypeName(SelectedFolder), "Folder") = 0 Then
Wscript.Quit
Else
OldString = InputBox("Enter the characters in the filename that you want to replace","Rename Files")
If OldString = "" Then Wscript.Quit

NewString = InputBox("Enter the characters that you want to replace them with","Rename Files")
If NewString = "" Then Wscript.Quit
End If

FullPath = SelectedFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(SelectedFolder.Title).Path

Set TheFolder = FileManagement.GetFolder(FullPath)
Set FileList = TheFolder.Files
Success = 0


ThisFile = File.Name
TheString = InStr(ThisFile, OldString)
AlreadyRenamed = InStr(ThisFile, "%")

If (TheString <> 0) AND (AlreadyRenamed = 0) Then
Success = 1

TempName = Replace(ThisFile, OldString, NewString)
FlagName = "%" + TempName
File.Name = FlagName
End If
Next

For Each File in FileList
ThisFile = File.Name
FindFlag = InStr(ThisFile, "%")


If FindFlag <> 0 Then
NewName = Replace(ThisFile, "%", "")
File.Name = NewName
End If
Next

'Move the files
For Each File in FileList
FileManagement.MoveFile "C:\Users\lislej\Desktop\test_move\*.log", "C:\Users\lislej\Desktop\test_move_to\"
Next

If Success = 1 Then
Dummy = WshShell.Popup ("Rename Files operation complete!",5,"Rename Files",64)
Else
Dummy = WshShell.Popup ("Rename Files operation failed! Please repeat the operation.",0,"Rename Files",16)
End If

Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code shown is missing something as there is a `Next` without `For`. But the file move part is intact and that's where you should check for the filename to skip:

```
Set FileList = TheFolder.Files
'Move the files
For Each File in FileList
    If InStr(File, "delete_junkfiles") = 0 Then
        ' If "delete_junkfiles" is not find in the filename then do move file
        File.Move "C:\Users\lislej\Desktop\test_move_to\"
    End If
Next
```

UPDATE:

I think you need to refresh the FileList after you renamed the files?

Comment: Thanks @PatricK, you're right, when I copied and pasted the code, it left out part of the for loop....thanks for help, but I think I need to explain my problem a little better

Comment: I've described the problem I'm having a bit better, it's part of the comments replying to @Oracle above, thanks again

Comment: @JohnLisle After some thoughts, I think the `FileList` needs to be reloaded after you renamed them? And you should be able to just call `File.Move`.

Comment: you're a legend @PatricK, thanks heaps buddy, that did the trick, although it still renames the delete_junkfiles.log, it doesn't get moved, which is mainly what I was concerned, I can fix the rename problem, it seems so obvious now that you've pointed it out lol, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think both ignoring the `delete_junkfiles.log`  file and your File Not Found error would be solved by changing

```
'Move the files
For Each File in FileList
FileManagement.MoveFile "C:\Users\lislej\Desktop\test_move\*.log", "C:\Users\lislej\Desktop\test_move_to\"
Next
```

to

```
'Move the files
For Each File in FileList
    if File.Name <> "delete_junkfiles.log" then 
        FileManagement.MoveFile File.Path, "C:\Users\lislej\Desktop\test_move_to\"
    end if
Next
```

Basically, what you were doing was looping through each file but using a wildcard in the `MoveFile()` call anyway. This was probably causing the File Not Found because the first iteration would have moved *all* the files matching the pattern. The second iteration would have found no files, hence the error. I added the `if` to avoid the file you wanted to ignore.

Comment: Thanks @oracle certified professional, I tried your addition to my code and it has fixed my file not found problem, thank you, but it still renames and moves everything.

Comment: Thanks @oracle I tried your addition to my code and it has fixed my file not found problem, thank you, but it still renames and moves everything. I think I need to clarify little better basically I have a folder with files named FTPPub1_aaplog.ftp.log, FTPPub1_netdesklog.ftp.log, TPurge.log, TPurge_Others.log and a delete_junkfiles.log,all files except the delete_junkfiles.log should get renamed then moved, then log files are regenerated with the original file names, the delete_junkfiles must remain untouched. I know there is an easy way to do this, but I think I'm too close to the problem lol